# Page refresh after click on register in jquery ajax php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

page refreshes after data submitted.

register.php

```
    <head>
      <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    
    
    
    <div class="container">
      <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Register Now</button>
    
      <!-- Modal -->
      <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
        
          <!-- Modal content-->
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <h4 class="modal-title bg-primary text-center">Register</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" id="away">
         
                <form method="post" name="form" id="login" align="center">
                Email:<input type="email" name="email" id="email"  placeholder="email"  autocomplete="off" required/> <br/>  <br/>
                Password:<input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="password" required> <br/> <br/>
                <input type="submit" id="register" name="register" value="Create Account" class="btn btn-info  save" /> &nbsp;
    
                <a class="btn btn-info" href="login.php" > Login </a>
                </form>
    
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
            <script>
                     $(document).ready(function(){                     
                        $('#register').on('click',function(){
                         var email = $('#email').val();
                         var password = $('#password').val();
    
                         $.ajax({
                            method:"POST",
                            url:"registeruser.php",
                            data:{ email:email, password:password},
                        });
                        });              
                        });
                       
                     
            </script>
```

registeruser.php

```
<?php
include('db.php');

if(isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['password']) ) 
{
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $query = "insert into newtable (email,password) values ('$email','$password')";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);


}


?>
```

The problem is that, my data is submitted successfully, but i used ajax jquery. my data is submitted and page also refreshes. i don't want my page to refresh.
please help to find my mistake.
i also used event.preventDefault() function to stop refresh. but it also did not work. it stops full functionality to save data.

Comment: change `type="submit"` to `type="button"` it should work fine .

Comment: **Warning!** You are _wide open_ for [SQL injection](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/SQL_Injection) attacks! You should use parameterized [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of using completely unescaped user data directly in your queries like that. _Never ever ever never_ trust user input.

Comment: _**Never ever** ever never_ store passwords in plain text! You should _always_ hash the passwords using [password_hash()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and only store the hashes. Then you can use [password_verify()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) to verify a password against a hash.

Comment: Don't change the button to `type="submit"` - you break the default functionality of being able to submit the form by pressing return, which is vital for accessibility. Do it properly and listen for the `submit` event of the `form` element instead of the `click` of a `button`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest approach is probably to make the button no longer be a "submit" button:

```
<input type="button" id="register" name="register" value="Create Account" class="btn btn-info save" />
```

or:

```
<button type="button" id="register" class="btn btn-info save">Create Account</button>
```

---

Additionally, if you don't want to post a `<form>` and aren't otherwise using that `<form>`, you can simply remove that element entirely:

```
<div class="modal-body" id="away">
    Email:<input type="email" name="email" id="email"  placeholder="email"  autocomplete="off" required/> <br/>  <br/>
    Password:<input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="password" required> <br/> <br/>
    <input type="submit" id="register" name="register" value="Create Account" class="btn btn-info  save" /> &nbsp;
    <a class="btn btn-info" href="login.php" > Login </a>
</div>
```

That way there'd be nothing to accidentally be submitted in the first place.